# How to merge (transfer) one layer into another PostGIS layer?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I want to merge two layers which have identical structure.

First layer is from postgres database table say "layer1" and  other layer is shapefile say "layer2". I want to merge layer2 "INTO" layer1 (NOT third layer).

I tried to copy paste in editing mode but it does not add attributes. any suggestions?

Note: the main layer is layer1 -postgresql database table.

[image: attribute table]

Comment: Copying should bring in attributes if the column names are the same. I would double check your attributes actually have the same names.

Comment: You need to define "merge" here. Do you mean (1) you want to *add* the shapefile to the table layer1? Or, (2) that you want to update the table (perhaps by GID) with the results of the shapefile (newer or better data), or (3) a combination of both new entries and updates. Until this information is added, I vote to close the question. It's unclear what is being asked. There is no sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the merge tool wish merge a lot of shp to one

[image: Merge tool]

Comment: elmo  yes i saw that but it gives third layer which i don't want .

Comment: also my main layer is Postgresql table which is not supported in merge tool.

Comment: can you perfom an attribute join using your gid column?